# No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, windows-server-2008-r2

I have rather a frustrating issue in that I'm getting errors appearing in the logs relating to queries that cannot run or complete, which is odd as the pages are normally fine, further investigation shows the error:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

I am running Tomcat 6 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacentre (1 CPU), MySQL 5.0.85 with mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.

I've not experienced any pages throw errors when I access our websites, but some users must be experiencing an issue, hence the error logs. Needle in a haystack pops to mind, if anyone could please shed some light as to a resolution it would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than one core in your CPU, this is usually due to a bug (ID 2577795)  in Windows Server 2008 R2. A hotfix is available from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2577795).

Comment: Single CPU as previously mentioned, so the fix I feel will not help, but thank you.

Comment: I forward this suggestion to the hosting company, at first they disagreed but then changed their mind so not sure what was going on, they've applied the patch but unfortunately this still hasn't cured the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated all projects to Tomcat 7.0.42 and my errors have disappeared, our websites are far more stable and slightly faster, we are using less memory and cpu usage is far better.